# Datatables Error when using destroy(): Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How I use **DataTables**:

1. Fetch data from the db.
2. Convert the data to row objects using **Underscore.js** template.
3. Populate my table's `<tbody>` with the rows.
4. Then I init the Datatable on the table that I have.

The problem is when I try to add more rows to the table, I am not using the API so I just add rows directly to the `<tbody>` and I want DataTables to **ReInit** it self using the new `<tbody>`.

I am trying to [Destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) the table, but what happens is that I get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The
>   node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of
>   this node.(…)

I created a [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/guXUsqah2p7TpnsjQVBo?p=preview) to reproduce what I am trying to do using Datatables but it doesn't reproduce the error...

Here is a question I found about the same error:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28081/how-to-update-table-when-dom-changes-destroy-init-crash

Answer (score 1):

You just need add   **"retrieve": true,** option into your datatable configuration.

```
function init(){
    ruleChangeLogTable = $('#changeLogTable').DataTable({
      //I use destroy because I want to recreate the table with new data.
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
             "retrieve": true,              // this option is added
            "bInfo": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "dom": '<"#searchInput"f>',
            "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" },
            "columns": [ 
            null,
                null,
                null,
                null, 
                 null
            ]
        });
    }
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve  for more details refer this

Hope this helps you

Comment: It didn't work for me, it worked only when I used the destroy function and when I use the destroy function in my computer I get an error:
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.(…)

Comment: don't detroy the datatable as you have given the demo in that just added the "retrieve": true, it works for me

Comment: No when clear search previous table getting display.But Warning: Cannot reinitialise Datatable... this error is gone away

Comment: Take a look at the updated Demo and question, It works in the demo but in my computer I get that error.

Comment: You need check datatable js version for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128264/discussion-between-dipak-thoke-and-offir-peer).

Answer (score 0):

no need to destroy and init, just redraw table using api

```
function Repopulate() {
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //init() //remove this line and add the one below
    $("#changeLogTable").DataTables().draw(); 
}
```

Comment: But when you type something in the search input and delete you will get the former table.

Comment: i guess you changed initial demo code. i can't reproduce what you asked.